# Matlab Sort 3D Matrix By Columns

Tags: matlab, sorting, matrix, multidimensional-array

I am trying to sort a 3D matrix in the form of 2x25x30 and sort by the second row along the 25 columns and doing this 30 times.  I have tried using the sort function with various results.  I keep getting a new matrix in the form of 2x750x30 using an index to sort the second row.
My data looks like -( 1991 1992 1993; 1000 3200 2100) ,
(1991 1992 1993; 3400 7000 5500) but in a 2x25x30 
matrix.  The 1st row are calendar years and these need to be maintained in the final output.  The sort is based on the second row.  Thank you!

Comment: what do you mean sort by second row?  You can sort by first dimension, second or third.

Comment: It may be helpful to provide some code which creates the data and your expected output.

Comment: In the 2x25x30 it is the row that are not the calendar years, which act as headers.  In the example, calendar years are 1991, 1992, 1993.  I'm not sorting on this row but the row below that.  Thank you

Comment: Final result is 1991 1993 1992 ; 1000 2100 3200 and for the second iteration 1991 1993 1992; 3400 5500 7000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Approach #1**

With `A` as the input array, you can use linear-indexing helped by [`broadcasting with bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) -

```
[m,n,r] = size(A);
[~,idx] = sort(A(2,:,:))
idx2D = bsxfun(@plus,(idx-1)*m,(1:size(A,1))')
idx3D = bsxfun(@plus,idx2D,permute(m*n*(0:1),[1,3,2]))
out = A(idx3D)
```

Sample input, output -

```
A(:,:,1) =
        1991        1992        1993
        1000        3200        2100
A(:,:,2) =
        1991        1992        1993
        3400        7000        5500
out(:,:,1) =
        1991        1993        1992
        1000        2100        3200
out(:,:,2) =
        1991        1993        1992
        3400        5500        7000
```

With automatic broadcasting in MATLAB 2016B, it would look a lot neater, like so -

```
[m,n,r] = size(A);
[~,idx] = sort(A(2,:,:))
out = A((1:size(A,1))' + (idx-1)*m + permute(m*n*(0:r-1),[1,3,2]))
```

---

**Approach #2**

Again using `bsxfun`, but this time with column-indexing on 2D reshaped array that helps avoid the second *bsxfun-ing*, like so  -

```
[m,n,r] = size(A);
[~,idx] = sort(A(2,:,:));
out = reshape(A(:,bsxfun(@plus,squeeze(idx),n*(0:r-1))),m,n,r)
```

Comment: Approach #2 is terrific!  Can you explain how bsxfun and squeeze are working together with 'reshape'?  thank you